# Can I send a string to the system pager in Elixir?

Tags: shell, elixir, pager

I'm writing a little command-line app in Elixir, and trying to display some data in a paged format, similar to e.g. `git log`.

I've tried to approach this by using Elixir's and Erlang's built-in capabilities to send commands to the shell, i.e.:

```
System.cmd("ls | less", []) # Erlang error: :enoent
:os.cmd(:"ls | less") # Silently exits
```

Neither of these approaches has worked for me.

Comment: `:os.cmd/1` expects a charlist, not an atom, hence the correct syntax would be `:os.cmd('ls')` (note single quotes.) But I frankly doubt you might expect wrappers to work properly with a system pager in general.

Comment: `:os.cmd/1` works with atoms and character lists. I agree regarding the pager though.

By the way, to run piped command with `System.cmd/2`:


`{files, _code} = System.cmd("sh", ["-c", "ls | less"])`.


Also :os.cmd(:"ls | less") should work fine too.

Comment: `less` will not do any pagination if the output is not headed to a terminal. See this for some more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/how-to-trick-a-command-into-thinking-its-output-is-going-to-a-terminal